# Releasing Mac App Store application that requires 3rd party drivers

Tags: macos, driver, mac-app-store

Anyone has any experience with application deployment through Mac App Store with 3rd party drivers? I have an application that is used to manage external device through usb port. It requires some drivers to be installed within. Any ideas how to deploy such application with Mac App Store so I don't have to bother user with any confusing messages about drivers? Is there any way to deploy such driver? Is there any way to load drivers only in userspace (sandbox?)

It's a virtual com port driver.

Comment: What kind of "driver"? kernel extension? or a daemon? if deamon, does it need to be run as root? how is it launched? do you have the rights to distribute  the 3rd software? or to be downloaded separately?

Comment: virtual com port driver

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you can use the user space I/O Kit framework from Mac App Store apps. So if your device can be driven entirely via that, go ahead. USB devices are usually good candidates for user space drivers, but it heavily depends on how the device will be used. If only your app is going to be accessing the device, you stand a very good chance. If you're intending to make it available to multiple applications, e.g. by creating a /dev node, you'll need to drop to the kernel.

You can't ship kernel extensions (kexts) with apps via the Mac App Store.

I don't know what the status is regarding MAS apps which require a specific device and kext to work, without shipping the kext together with the app. If the kext is optional, I suspect they'll allow it.